# how to sum Stacked In Line sql

Tags: sql

i have a table like this

```
code  Quantity
1      5
1      6
2      2
2      1-
3      4
.
.
```

how can made it like this

```
code  Quantity  remain
1      5          5
1      6          11
2      2          2
2      1-         1
3      4          4
.
.
```

Comment: Your results presume an ordering of the rows.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Do you have a column that specifies the ordering?

Answer (score 1):

Your query presumes an ordering of the rows.  I will assume you have such a column.

Assuming the values are numbers (`1-` ???), then you can simply use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(quantity) over (partition by code order by ?) as remaining
from t;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a window sum, *but* you need a column to unambiguously order the records within groups sharing the same `code`. I assumed that this column is called `id`.

```
select t.*, sum(quantity) over(partition by code order by id) remain from mytable t
```